# I can't run tf_upgrade_v2 to migrate to tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to do the following steps to migrate from TensorFlow 1 to TensorFlow 2: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade. I can do this in Google Colab but I can't do this on my laptop.

To do so, I first tried to run the following command in Powershell (I'm on Windows, also my working directory contains the project folder):

```
tf_upgrade_v2 --intree project/ --outtree project2/ --reportfile report.txt
```

It says that "The term 'tf_upgrade_v2' is not recognized ..."
Then, I downloaded file tf_upgrade_v2.py from the TensorFlow repository and tries to run the following command:

```
python tf_upgrade_v2.py --intree project/ --outtree project2/ --reportfile report.txt
```

It works for some time, then finishes, but there is no changes in the folder.
Finally, I tried this:

```
tf_upgrade_v2.py --intree project/ --outtree projects2/ --reportfile report.txt
```

It opens another terminal for some time, then finishes, but there is no changes.

I have TensorFlow 2.0 according to `pip list`. I use conda

UPD:
`conda list` doesn't contain tensorflow, only tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator, tensorflow-hub

Comment: Goto  path where python is installed. Then go to bin. There you will find tf_upgrade_v2. Run the above command here.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, running python on windows using Visual Studio 2019. The short version, if you already know the location of the upgrade script, is instead of `tf_upgrade_v2.py` I needed to run `tf_upgrade_v2_main.py` as the former simply ran and did nothing.

**Detailed steps:**

The actual steps to running the upgrade script were more involved to figure out. TLDR; from the folder where you want to perform the upgrade run the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\tools\compatibility\tf_upgrade_v2_main.py" --infile NeuralTransfer-tf1.py --outfile NeuralTransfer-tf2.py
```

Be sure to replace `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\` with the path to your python install directory as needed. Also be sure to set the --infile and --outfile arguments accordingly.

To locate `tf_upgrade_v2.py`, which per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade) should be installed with TensorFlow 1.13 and later (including all TF 2.0 builds), simply search for the file in your python install directory in windows explorer.

In my case `tf_upgrade_v2.py` was located (relative to the install directory) in `Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\tools\compatibility\tf_upgrade_v2_main.py` as shown in the command line arguments above.
It can be also located under `c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python_xx\site-packages` (if pip is used `pip show tensorflow` can be used)

Answer (score -1):

For me it is working by following line of code.

```
!tf_upgrade_v2 \
    --intree models/xyz/cookbook/ROL/ \
    --outtree Rol_v2/ \
    --reportfile tree_report.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

For colab run this:

```
os.environ.get("tf_upgrade_v2")
```

And then this:

```
!tf_upgrade_v2 \
    --intree xyz \
    --outtree zyx \
    --reportfile xyzyx
```