# TensorFlow: Upgrading code with TF1 to TF2 with tf_upgrade_v2

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

When I try to run tf_upgrade_v2 on a project I get this error message:

`"C:\Users\jimin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\tools\compatibility\ast_edits.py", line 933, in update_string_pasta t = pasta.parse(text) AttributeError: module 'pasta' has no attribute 'parse'`

This problem has apparently appeared before(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29070), but the solution (downgrading pasta to 1.7.1) does not work for me. I use Win10, Python 3.9.12, TensorFlow 2.8.0

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67038443/14290681) reference help you to solve this issue.

Comment: @user11530462 those are good instructions to reproduce the issue, but they don't offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Install `google-pasta`. I'm installing `tensorflow==2.2.0` which requires `google-pasta==1.8.0` or newer. It appears that the requested version of `google-pasta` is `google-pasta>=0.1.6` so pip installed version `0.2.0`. Explicitly requesting version `1.8.0` fixed the issue for me.